# How to run "Deployd" on port 80 instead of port 5000 in webserver.

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, deployd

Im running a website with "deployd" and I having issues to change my applicaiton of running on port 5000 to port 80. What I want to do is instead of having "mydomain.com:5000", I just want to have "mydomain.com"

Thank you.

Comment: Do not forget to secure your dashboard if you make it public.
https://github.com/deployd/deployd/issues/110

Comment: imho best practice is to use apache or nginx as proxy listening to port 80 and forwarding the requests to nodejs (any other port) or something else (incl. application server like tomcat))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to these docs of the internal API:
http://docs.deployd.com/docs/developing-modules/internal-api/server.html

You can pass in an options object when creating the server. So something like this should work

```
var deployd = require('deployd'),
    options = {
      port : 80
    },
    server = deployd(options);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but didn´t work becuase im using apache and the port 80 its already in use. Apparently a better solution would use nginx.

Comment: Ah, what you might want to do is port forwarding. Have the the node server run on port 5000 and then forward the request to port 5000. You would have to check apache/nginx docs on how to do that.

Comment: You want to use a reverse proxy not a port forward, that's completely different...

Comment: @JasonM your link is broken