# Deployd (Node.js) only accepts local connections

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, connection, server, deployd

I can't connect to my [deployd](https://github.com/deployd/deployd) server externally on [45.55.183.253:5000](http://45.55.183.253:5000). I can connect to it locally with no problems.

I am running ubuntu 12.04 at Digital Ocean.

A `netstat -ntap` shows the following:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8906/nodejs
```

The code used for the server is taken from the documentation. I have tested with adding both port and server location in `.listen()`. The script is run with [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever). But I have also tested with just running the script with node.

I have also tested with the test server from the [node.js page](http://nodejs.org), with and without the port and server as argument to `.listen()`. Still with no luck.

Is there any configuration that I need to do to allow the server to be accessed externally? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your router/firewall/etc so the public IP at port 5000 matches the local IP of the computer the server is running on.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263545/how-to-run-deployd-on-port-80-instead-of-port-5000-in-webserver/17264362#17264362) I would use apache or nginx as reverse proxy. If your are using apache you can install [mod proxy html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/). After installing you have to configure your conf-file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ...
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /ejabberd/ http://127.0.0.1:5281/
    ProxyPassReverse /ejabberd/ http://127.0.0.1:5281/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```